# Android multithreading data

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

How take process multithreaded load for the item list. I get from api list string elements. Next need to get data for items this list. Load need to use rxjava. Result need do getting to the single subscribe.

Comment: You can google any RxJava tutorial.

Comment: You can get your items firstly,then use operator flatMap to handle each item,finally subscribe it.

Answer (score 0):

> Next need to get data for items this list

What it has to be? Just method inside your class or separate network request for each of strings?

For first case:

```
getListFromApi()
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
    .map { getSomeData(it) }
    .toList()
    .subscribe()
```

Second case:

```
getListFromApi()
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
    .map { requestForSomeData(it) }
    .toList()
    .flatMap { flowablesList -> Single.zip(flowablesList.map { it.firstOrError() }) { it.toList() } }
    .subscribe()
```